# failed: "/data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit

Tags: android, webview

dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
com.github.lzyzsd.jsbridge.BridgeWebView.(BridgeWebView.java:44)

Comment: Has nothing to do with the objective content particular question, but: when do people learn, how to [state a proper](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question? This includes a meaningful topic, proper text in the question itself as well as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).